# SQL Server - Iterate, aggregate, and insert

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find an efficient way to aggregate data for reporting. Let's say I need to aggregate the following data in 5-second intervals:

```
CREATE TABLE RawData
(
    Result                          FLOAT,
    CaptureTime                     DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO RawData VALUES
(2.3, '2018-04-01 00:00:00'),
(2.5, '2018-04-01 00:00:01'),
(2.8, '2018-04-01 00:00:02'),
(2.8, '2018-04-01 00:00:03'),
(3.4, '2018-04-01 00:00:04'),
(5.1, '2018-04-01 00:00:05'),
(2.2, '2018-04-01 00:00:06'),
(4.1, '2018-04-01 00:00:07'),
(4.3, '2018-04-01 00:00:08'),
(5.9, '2018-04-01 00:00:09'),
...
```

The aggregated data will be stored in another table:

```
CREATE TABLE AggregateData
(
    Result                          FLOAT,
    StartCaptureTime                DATETIME,
    EndCaptureTime                  DATETIME
);
```

As an example: if my aggregate function is `SUM`, the data in `AggregateData` would be:

```
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Result |   StartCaptureTime   |    EndCaptureTime   |
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  13.8  | 2018-04-01 00:00:00  | 2018-04-01 00:00:05 |
|  21.6  | 2018-04-01 00:00:05  | 2018-04-01 00:00:10 |
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

The best solution that I've come up with uses a loop:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPerformAggregateCalculation]
    @UpdateIntervalSeconds          INT,
    @StartTime                      DATETIME,
    @EndTime                        DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RunningStartTime       DATETIME = @StartTime;
    DECLARE @RunningEndTime         DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, @UpdateIntervalSeconds, @RunningStartTime);
    DECLARE @AggregateValue         FLOAT;

    WHILE @RunningStartTime < @EndTime
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AggregateValue =
        (
            SELECT SUM(Result)
            FROM RawData
            WHERE CaptureTime >= @RunningStartTime AND CaptureTime < @RunningEndTime
        );

        INSERT INTO AggregateData VALUES
            (@AggregateValue, @RunningStartTime, @RunningEndTime);

        SELECT
            @RunningStartTime = @RunningEndTime,
            @RunningEndTime = DATEADD(SECOND, @UpdateIntervalSeconds, @RunningEndTime);
    END
END

EXEC spPerformAggregateCalculation
    @UpdateIntervalSeconds = 5,
    @StartTime = '2018-04-01 00:00:00',
    @EndTime = '2018-04-01 00:00:10'
```

Is there a more efficient way to get this data? I'll be performing more complex aggregations on millions of rows on a daily basis, so every bit helps.

P.S. In case "increase your interval" is offered as a suggestion, my data will actually be aggregated in much larger intervals than 5 seconds; I just whittled the problem down for the example.

---

### Update

Below was my final solution, based dnoeth's answer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPerformAggregateCalculation]
    @UpdateIntervalSeconds          INT,
    @StartTime                      DATETIME,
    @EndTime                        DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
            -- Adjust each CaptureTime to the beginning of the interval.
            DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartTime , CaptureTime) % @UpdateIntervalSeconds, CaptureTime) as StartCaptureTime,
            Result
       FROM RawData
       WHERE CaptureTime >= @StartTime
    )
    INSERT INTO AggregateData
    SELECT
        SUM(Result),
        StartCaptureTime,
        DATEADD(SECOND, @UpdateIntervalSeconds, StartCaptureTime)
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY StartCaptureTime
    ORDER BY StartCaptureTime;
END
```

Comment: Is it always 5 rows.  Can time skip or duplicate?

Comment: Good question. It is always 5 rows and there are no skips or duplicates.

Comment: Then there is a very simple solution but you don't to be enthused with my answer.

Comment: A simple solution, in addition to the one you already answered, or are you referring to your answer below? I haven't had time to test it yet.

Comment: Should the intervals always start at `00` or at the minimum `CaptureTime`? And what are those *much larger intervals than 5 seconds*?

Comment: @dnoeth The interval will always start at the `StartCaptureTime`. My interval is configurable, but 15 minutes is realistic. My data is logged every second, though, so it was easier to create a test case using an interval in seconds instead of minutes.

Comment: Then my query should fit, simply switch to 900 seconds :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a cursor or recursion, both are not really performant for larger amounts of data.

Simply adjust the CaptureTime to the start of each interval.

```
declare @UpdateIntervalSeconds integer = 5;
declare @minTime datetime = (select min(CaptureTime) from RawData);
-- if you want to start at exactly `00` instead of `01`,`02` etc. 
-- you can modify `@minTime` using another DATEADD/DATEDIFF

with cte as
 ( select 
      -- adjust each CaptureTime to the begin of an interval
      DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEDIFF(SECOND, @minTime , CaptureTime) % @UpdateIntervalSeconds, CaptureTime) as StartCaptureTime
     ,Result
   from RawData
 )
select StartCaptureTime
  ,DATEADD(SECOND, @UpdateIntervalSeconds, StartCaptureTime) AS EndCaptureTime
  ,sum(Result)
from cte
group by StartCaptureTime
order by StartCaptureTime
```

Comment: Very clever! I just had to add a filter to the CTE to make it work with a passed-in Start Time instead processing the entire table at once. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with the cursor.

I think a recursive cte is more efficient and cleaner here.

```
INSERT INTO @RawData VALUES
(2.3, '2018-04-01 00:00:00'),
(2.5, '2018-04-01 00:00:01'),
(2.8, '2018-04-01 00:00:02'),
(2.8, '2018-04-01 00:00:03'),
(3.4, '2018-04-01 00:00:04'),
(5.1, '2018-04-01 00:00:05'),
(2.2, '2018-04-01 00:00:06'),
(4.1, '2018-04-01 00:00:07'),
(4.3, '2018-04-01 00:00:08'),
(5.9, '2018-04-01 00:00:09');
declare @start datetime = (select min(CaptureTime) from @RawData);
declare @end datetime   = (select max(CaptureTime) from @RawData);
with cte as 
(  select @start st,          DATEADD(ss, 4, @start) as ed
   union all 
   select DATEADD(ss, 5, st), DATEADD(ss, 5, ed)
   from cte 
   where ed < @end
)
select sum(rd.Result), cte.st, cte.ed 
  from @RawData rd 
  join cte 
    on rd.CaptureTime between cte.st and cte.ed 
 group by cte.st, cte.ed;
```